# I can't get Angular Routing to work properly

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes

I am working on an Angular website with Firebase as the backend. I'm using routing and would like to redirect the default url to a login page but nothing is appearing. All of the routes seem to be correct. Any help?

app.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { initializeApp,provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAuth,getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]  
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

login.component.html:

```html
<h1 style="font-size: large;">Somthing</h1>
```

login.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/shared/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  email: string = "";
  password: string = "";

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  login() {
    this.auth.login(this.email, this.password);
  }

}
```

index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AnGenWebsite</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try adding the following route:

```
{path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
```

The '**' path is the one that has the behaviour you are expecting.

So the "app-routing.module.ts:" should look something like this:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {DashboardComponent} from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './components/login/login.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from './components/register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But that still doesn't seem to work. Something I forgot to include in the original post was my index.html file, but all that does in the body is link straight to my app-root.